# Integer overflow in memory_limit check detected -- Cannot set memory limit past 2gb?

Tags: php

I'm running PHP 5.1.6 with a 64-bit platform, 7.5 GB memory.  I have the memory_limit set to 4 gigs.

I'm zipped a large amount of files (output size ~= 2gb), so I need this memory available.

When zipping the largest of my files, those that approach the 2gb limit I've imposed, the script fails with:

```
Integer overflow in memory_limit check detected
```

I am assuming this has to do with the integer that is holding the memory_limit and it must be 32-bit.   Is there a way to work around this or can I only set my memory limit to 2048M?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [known bug](http://www.mail-archive.com/php-bugs@lists.php.net/msg89181.html) - please upgrade to the latest version of PHP :)

p.s. there is an addendum [here](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39132&edit=1) which suggests that if the problem persists, use 4000000000 instead of 4GB in the memory_limit directive

Comment: Doh.  Thanks.  I googled about a bit and saw the bug status, but didn't see the 'workaround.'  It's for an ec2 ami I built and I'd hate to rebuild the thing.  I'll try the 4000000000.  

Thanks!