# PHP 5.1.6 Integer overflow in memory_limit check detected

Tags: php, memory, integer, overflow, limit

I have a script that ends every time with this error:

`Integer overflow in memory_limit check detected` even if I set the memory limit to `10Gb` or `-1` (unlimited).

The script turns on a `64bit` Linux server with `16Gb RAM`.

I have seen that this is fixed in recent PHP versions, but what can I do for my actual version ?

Comment: Is this any help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760396/integer-overflow-in-memory-limit-check-detected-cannot-set-memory-limit-past

Comment: PHP version 5.1.6 is no longer officially supported (in fact it's been out of the support cycle for about 10 years). It has many many known security vulnerabilities and bugs which at this point are probably exploitable by automated crawlers. It's advisable you upgrade your PHP version to one that is officially supported.